# How to add Lusca Security for Express API REST with Angular and Android Native app like Clients?

Tags: android, rest, security, express, csrf-protection

I don't sure what is the best option to add a CSRF Token for my form's in the website and still using the same endpoints for my Android App :/

I can create new endpoints for android but i think that is not a good solution because someone can send a CSRF attack to the Mobile endpoints instead the web endpoints :/... so at the end that solution is the same of don't use Lusca at all.

What you think is the best, secure and correct way to add security to Rest API used by Mobile Applications and maybe others servers?

Thanks.